# Find $\lim (a_{n+1}^\alpha-a_n^\alpha)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume $\alpha \in (0,1)$, and $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly monotone increasing positive series. and $\{a_{n+1}-a_n\}$ is bounded. Find $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(a_{n+1}^\alpha - a_{n}^\alpha)$$.

---

My idea is first proving for rational numbers , then use a rational sequences to approximate real numbers. But I can only prove for rational numbers.
If $\alpha \in \Bbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$: $$a_{n+1}^\alpha - a_{n}^\alpha = a_{n+1}^{\frac{q}{p}} - a_{n}^{\frac{q}{p}}=\frac{\left((a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}-(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)\left((a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-2}{p}}(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\cdots+(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}\right)}{(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-2}{p}}(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\cdots+(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}=\frac{a_{n+1}^q-a_n^q}{(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-2}{p}}(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\cdots+(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}=(a_{n+1}-a_n)\frac{(a_{n+1}^{q-1}+\cdots+a_n^{q-1})}{(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-2}{p}}(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\cdots+(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}}$$
For $\{a_n\}$ is a strictly monotone increasing positive series. then $\lim a_n = a$ or $\lim a_n = +\infty$

If $\lim a_n = a$. then $\exists M>0$. such that $$\left| \frac{(a_{n+1}^{q-1}+\cdots+a_n^{q-1})}{(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-2}{p}}(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\cdots+(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}} \right|<M$$. So $0\leq\lim (a_{n+1}^\alpha-a_n^\alpha) \leq \lim (a_{n+1}-a_n) M=0$

If $\lim a_n = +\infty$, then $$\frac{(a_{n+1}^{q-1}+\cdots+a_n^{q-1})}{(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}+(a_{n+1}^q)^{\frac{p-2}{p}}(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}+\cdots+(a_{n}^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}} \rightarrow 0$$
So for rational numbers, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_{n+1}^\alpha - a_n^\alpha) = 0$
For $\alpha \in (0,1)$, I choose $\alpha_k \in \Bbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$, and $\lim \alpha_k = \alpha$.  But I can't construct the following relationship $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}(a_{n+1}^{\alpha_k}-a_{n}^{\alpha_k}) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_{n+1}^{\alpha_k}-a_{n}^{\alpha_k})$$

---

I want to follow this way to extend the index from rational numbers to real numbers. But I failed. Can we solve this problem using this method? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: See also: [Seeking for a hint to a limit question $\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_{n+1}^{\alpha}-a_n^{\alpha})=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1438838).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n$ is bounded, then the limit is $0$. If $a_n\to \infty$ , use $(1+x)^\alpha<1+\alpha x$:

$$0<a_{n+1}^\alpha-a_n^\alpha=\alpha_n^\alpha(1+\frac {a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n})^\alpha<\alpha a_n^\alpha\frac {a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_n}\to 0$$
Hence the limit is $0$.